# Why does Neo4j 3.1.x return empty for relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using 3.1.5 and the example from the Neo4j documentation:

To return a relationship, just include it in the RETURN list.

Query.

```
MATCH (n { name: 'A' })-[r:KNOWS]->(c)
RETURN r
```

The relationship is returned by the example.

```
Table 3.63. Result
r
1 row
:KNOWS[0]\{\}
```

returns empty for the relationship. As far as I can tell, all return 'relationship' results in

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "columns": [
        "r"
      ],
      "data": [
        {
          "row": [
            {}
          ],
          "meta": [
            {
              "id": 927,
              "type": "relationship",
              "deleted": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "errors": []
}
```

Is this a change? A known-issue? The way it always was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the way it always was for JSON result (ie. via the HTTP connector).

In JSON, neo4j return all relationship's property.

If you use a a driver for Bolt connector, you will recieve a `Relationship` object with the startId & endId node, relationship's type, and the properties.

Cheers

**UPDATE**

You have access to the relationship's properties.

With this dataset : `MERGE (:Test {id:1})-[:REL {value:'Test'}]->(:Test {id:2})`

Via this curl command :

```
curl -v  http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit -u neo4j:admin --data  '{"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (:Test)-[r:REL]->(:Test) RETURN r"}]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Result is :

```
{"results":[{"columns":["r"],"data":[{"row":[{"value":"Test"}],"meta":[{"id":273,"type":"relationship","deleted":false}]}]}],"errors":[]}
```

You see the extract **{"value":"Test"}** is your relationship !

Comment: ok. that sux. Clearly the documentation becomes cumbersome to note these cases, but given have rudimentary nature of the examples in the documentation its clearly not a focus for the team

Comment: I really hate to accept this as an actual answer, but at this point it seems correct. So basically, when using the HTTP transactional interface a developer has no access to relationships and their properties